# How to copy article from Joomla 2.5 site to Joomla 3 site?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla 2.5 site, and need to copy many articles to a new Joomla 3 site. I'm not upgrading the 2.5 site to 3, just need to copy the articles from the 2.5 site and add them to the Joomla 3 site.

Is there a way to use PHP to read the article from the 2.5 site and then insert the article into the Joomla 3 site?

Both are on the same server, and each has it's own DB. I can access both DBs in PHP, but adding an article seems pretty complicated because of the asset IDs.

Not asking for code exactly, just if there is a function in Joomla 3 that adds an article, I can use a foreach after loading the articles from the 2.5 table, and then insert the article.

TIA!

Sloan

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can copy the `#__content` table from the old Joomla database (the 2.5 database) to the `#__content` table of the new Joomla database (the 3.x database). You should also copy the `#__categories` table too from the old db to the new db.

If you don't want to use `phpMyAdmin`, then you can always use `j2xml` (although we do find it a bit unreliable).

Comment: You can't do that directly since the structures of the tables differ between Joomla versions. Also, there's the issue of the asset_id. Each content item needs an asset ID with the matching record in the assets table.

Comment: The asset ID is not critical. In fact, we clean up the `com_content.article` entries in the #__assets table in order to optimize the performance. Please check: http://www.itoctopus.com/creating-new-articles-on-your-joomla-website-is-taking-a-long-time-clean-your-assets-table

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the extension "SP Transfer" where you can choose by ID what articles to transfer. 
You can also use the extension "J2XML" an convert data from one site to another.